# Java code to rename a file and replace another file in same location

Tags: java, file

I have two files `file1.txt1` and `file2.txt` in the same location as `D:\Folder\`. I have different contents in both files. Now i want to rename `file2.txt` as `file1.txt` and replace the already existing `file1.txt`. This way only one file will be left, that will be named as `file1.txt` and the contents will be of the `file2.txt`. How can i do this in Java?

I have tried to do the following, but the first file gets deleted and the second file wont get renamed.

```
File file1 = new File("D:\\Folder\\file1.txt");
File file2 = new File("D:\\Folder\\file2.txt");
file1.delete();
file2.renameTo(new File("D:\\Folder\\file1.txt"));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? There's TONS of publicly available resources on how to edit files using Java that are just one Google search away. It's also much easier in Java 8 so it shouldn't be too hard for you. If you try something but can't get anywhere THEN you can ask what you're stuck on

Comment: Yes i have tried a few but they wont work..i will add what i have tried

Comment: What happened when you ran this code?

Comment: Check the return value of `delete` to make sure that it could be deleted - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()

Comment: when i run this file1 gets deleted and file2 is still there..but file2 is not getting renamed to file1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. Please find the solution

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextFileRenaming {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     //File directory
      File file = new File("C:/Folder/");

        // Reading directory contents
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        String name = null;
        for(File f : files){

            // Getting file name and deleting 
            if(f.getName() != null && f.getName().equals("file1.txt")){
                 name = f.getName();
                f.delete();

                // Renaming the file
                file.listFiles()[0].renameTo(new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\"+ name));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why iterating over all files in the folder, when the name of the file to be deleted is known? `new File("does.not.exist")` not even throw an exception if the file does not exist.

Comment: Are you aware that you will always rename the first file that is found in the directory (independent of its name)? I would not call this code "the solution".